# WooCommerce RestFul API URL showing 404 Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the Restful settings enabled on the settings page and I have create a user with access keys.

I am using the PHP library and im getting this reponse.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [code] => 404
                    [message] => cURL HTTP error 404
                )

        )

)
```

If i visit the url in the browser /wc-api/v1 I also get a 404 response. I have seen some mentions of changing Permalink structure but it doesn't say what too anywhere?

Any pointers? Greatly received :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so they settings I need were...

```
 Post name  http://www.dipdye.co.uk/sample-post/
```

and

```
 Shop base with category    http://www.dipdye.co.uk/shop/product-category/sample-product/
```

After further reading it seems any 'pretty' url will work, my main issue was it not updating my Web.config file (as Im on IIS) on Apache this would be the .htaccess file.

I can now see something when i visit the page in web browser.

Hope this help someone else too.